# Calculate time difference in UNIX_TIMESTAMP (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question in this process , do not know how to proceed ..

I have a mysql database which gets data of timestamp, user and control.

```
timestamp |    user   |   control
1426147200|   USER1  |    0
1426149000|   USER1  |    20
1426156200|   USER1  |    75
1426156200|   USER1  |    15
1426156200|   USER1  |    20
1426159800|   USER1  |    0
1426167000|   USER1  |    15
```

Today i do

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE control="0"
```

and display all records in a table where `control="0"` in php output while. But i want to output the time where the control time lapse in "0" together.

My need is, if Control of "USER1" is "0" zero and change to whatever other number up to zero, how much time lapse was done.

Calculate and store in a variable the value of the time difference.

```
timestamp |    user  |   control
1426147200|   USER1  |    0
1426159800|   USER1  |    0
```

Note: The difference of rows where Control "0" zero change to "X" value is of undefined rows in my database, need do be done dynamically.

Comment: so you need another column laps that will hold '20+75+15+20 = 130'? and another one the time difference(1426159800-1426147200) ? do you?

Comment: Hi Alex, greetings! No exactly, i need the time difference from row 1 to row 2 and from row 6 to row 7. The output must be row 1 containing time difference to row 2 and row 6 containing time difference from row 7, rows 2 and 7 will be 'excluded' from 'visual' output. I think i need one more column..  :)

Comment: too many words, just post your expected result record with formulas ho did you calculate it

Comment: Thanks, i've solved this question making a primary query when i "SELECT FROM X WHERE control='0'", store this on a variable and make while and a secondary query inside "SELECT WHERE timestamp>$timestamp LIMIT 1". When done, make all calc inside second loop.